# Dump memory of a process

Tags: c, linux, bash, memory-dump

When reading the /proc/$PID/maps you get the mapped memory regions.
Is ther a way to dump one of  this regions?

```
$ cat /proc/18448/maps
...[snip]...
0059e000-005b1000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 40         /usr/local/lib/libgstlightning.so.0.0.0
005b1000-005b2000 r--p 00012000 08:11 40         /usr/local/lib/libgstlightning.so.0.0.0
005b2000-005b3000 rw-p 00013000 08:11 40         /usr/local/lib/libgstlightning.so.0.0.0
...[snip]...
```

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Nah! Call [`ptrace()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ptrace) with `PTRACE ATTACH`. Then open [`/proc/<pid>/mem`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc), seek to the region offset, and read the length of the region as given in `/proc</pid>/maps`.

Here's a [program I wrote](https://github.com/anacrolix/archive/blob/master/tibia/butox/cutil/readmem.c) that does it in C. Here's a [module I wrote](https://github.com/anacrolix/archive/blob/master/tibia/butox/memutil.py) that does it in Python ([and the ptrace binding](https://github.com/anacrolix/archive/blob/master/tibia/butox/ptrace.py)). For the finish, a [program that dumps all regions of a process to files](https://github.com/anacrolix/archive/blob/master/tibia/butox/dump_memory.py).

Enjoy!

Answer (score 5):

You can attach gdb to the process then dump memory region of length X words starting at location L with this: `x/Xw L`.

Attaching gdb when you start your process is simple: `gdb ./executable` then `run`. If you need to attach to a running process, start gdb then `gdb attach pid` where pid is is the process ID you care about.

Comment: Thanks, :) I haven't thought about it

Comment: You can use a command line argument to attach to a running process: `gdb -p <pid>`.

Comment: Good to know. I've only used gdb seriously for remote targets.

Answer (score 4):

Using dd(1):

```
sudo dd if=/dev/mem bs=1 skip=$(( 16#0059e000 - 1 )) \
        count=$(( 16#005b1000 - 16#0059e000 + 1)) | hexdump -C
```