# Dump process memory on exit linux

Tags: linux, ulimit, procdump, gcore

I want to dump a process' memory when it exits. All the solutions I've seen using `gcore`, `gdb` or even [procdump for linux](https://github.com/Microsoft/ProcDump-for-Linux) dump the core in the middle of the execution and not exactly when it terminates

Procdump for windows has a very elegant solution for this, i.e. `-t` will allow procdump to create a dump when the process exits.

I stumbled on to `ulimit -c unlimited` but this again will only generate dumps for non-graceful exits.

The process I want a dump for can be **any** process and not exactly my application.

Comment: But when the process exits, there is nothing to dump because the process does not exist anymore. What do you mean by "process exits"?

Comment: install signal handler for your application, when its about to exit just dump using C code, following link does that in C https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342335/dump-memory-of-a-process

Comment: @ks1322, by when the process exits, what i mean is when it is about to exit. Exactly what windows' procdump `-t` option does.

Comment: @PrabhakarLad, It's not my process' memory i need dumped. It can be any process, I just need to have a process id and dump the memory right when the process is about to exit.

Comment: write a c application (install signal handler SIGCHILD),  fork a process for which you want to monitor and refer the link in my earlier post to dump the memory.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to mimic this behavior with gdb:

> Procdump for windows has a very elegant solution for this, i.e. -t will allow procdump to create a dump when the process exits.

First you create a file 'mycommand.txt':

```
b exit
r
generate-core-file ./core.1
q
```

Then you start your program with:

```
 gdb --command mycommand.txt yourprogram
```

you will have a file called core.1 in your working directory. Check with:

```
gdb yourprogram core.1
```

Comment: gdb command line should be `gdb -x mycommand.txt yourprogram`.